# Hover functionality for button inside ul li reacting as anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I am not able to use `<ul> <li>` hover and click..
Inside `<li>` tag I have `<button>` tag not `<a>` tag.
I want same hover and click functionality in button tag as anchor only.

My Css :

```
.custom-anchor:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #3276b1;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

My HTML :

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button id="csr_duration_btn"
            class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-xs btn-success"
            data-toggle="dropdown">{{csrServiceModel.selectedDuration.name}}<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <ul id="comparision-chart-interval" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li data-ng-repeat="duration in csrServiceModel.durations">
            <button class="btn btn-link custom-anchor" data-ng-click="csrServiceModel.durationSelect(duration)" ng-disabled="duration.enabled">{{ duration.name }}</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]
I tried to add same custom class for `<li>` tag also but it is not working.

It should work like below image :

[image]

Edited :

You can see ..... Some options are disabled in the lists.. Is there any way on click of disabled option list it should not do anything..

I want to prevent the event if disabled list option is clicked..

Please help...

Comment: could you add the other css markup?

Comment: it looks like bootstrap. Add following css rule: #comparision-chart-interval li button {width:100%;}

Comment: other css in default provided by bootstrap..

Comment: Edited:  You can see ..... Some options are disabled in the lists.. Is there any way on click of disabled option list it should not do anything.. 

I want to prevent the event if disabled list option is clicked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like formatting is done using bootstrap. Add following css rule:

```
#comparision-chart-interval li button {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! dude.. I tried this.. #comparision-chart-interval li button {
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}